# Assigning a struct in C++

Tags: c++

I have a struct defined with a constructor as such:

```
    struct Point {
    double x; double y; 
    Point (double xx=0, double yy=0): x(xx),y(yy){}; 
};
```

I can create points like this and this work fine,

```
Point P0(0,0), P1(1,1);
```

But I want to be able to modify it as such:

```
P0 = (4,5); //no compilation error but garbage returned when printing P0
```

Does not work!

Also, I have a function like I am using like this

```
void Foo(Point P0, Point P1){
...do stuff
}
```

and I want to pass the following argument like this:

```
Foo((1,2),(2,3)); //no compilation error but garbage returned
```

I tried looking all this up not really clear to me.. any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(4,5)` is equivalent to just `5`, since that's how the comma operator works: it evaluates the first expression, discards the result, then evaluates the second. You should get a compilation warning about a discarded expression with no side-effects, if you enable warnings.

In C++11, you can use a list initialiser to do what you want:

```
P0 = {4,5};
Foo({1,2},{2,3});
```

If you're stuck with an older dialect, you'll have to spell it out:

```
P0 = Point(4,5);
Foo(Point(1,2), Point(2,3));
```

Comment: Yes.. constructing is fine. How about modifying the values without having to go through all the member with the dot operator.. I don't have C++11

Comment: @Programmer: I don't know what you mean. The dot operator is how you access (and modify) class members; how else do you want to do it?

Comment: I will follow your suggestion. Yours was the first response so I have accepted you answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
P0 = (4,5);
```

This does not do what you think it does.

The expression `(4,5)` evaluates to `5`. This is because it contains what's called the *comma operator*. The comma operator first evaluates its left operand, throws away the result, and then evaluates its second operand. So this statement is really equivalent to

```
P0 = 5;
```

Now, *this* is in turn equivalent to

```
P0 = Point(5);
```

which is equivalent to

```
P0 = Point(5, 0);
```

since you have a default argument. It's not garbage at all. It's perfectly well-defined.

Precisely the same thing is going to happen in your other statement:

```
Foo((1,2),(2,3)); // same as Foo(Point(2, 0), Point(3, 0));
```

To fix this, you can construct the points explicitly:

```
P0 = Point(4, 5);
Foo(Point(1, 2), Point(2, 3));
```

or, if you have C++11 support, you can do this:

```
P0 = {4, 5};
Foo({1, 2}, {2, 3});
```

(When a comma occurs inside braces, it's *not* a comma operator. It separates elements of the initializer list.)

Comment: How about overloading the parenthesis operator?

Comment: @gat are you joking? Parentheses can't be overloaded.

Comment: Yes.. constructing is fine. How about modifying the values without having to go through all the memmber with  the dot operator.. I dont have C++11

Comment: @gat, oh, is that what you meant. Yeah, you can overload function call notation, but how would you propose to apply that here?

Comment: @Brian Bi: I was just thinking about how to make it closest to what he wants. Haven't come up with a solution yet. So I posted a comment, not an answer :D

Comment: Yes. I have VS2010 and compiler does not allow..error C2059,error C2143

Comment: @Programmer well just do `P0 = Point(4, 5)` then

Answer (score 2):

In this statement

```
P0 = (4,5); //no compilation error but garbage returned when printing P0
```

expression `(4,5)` is an expression with the comme operator. Its value is the second subexpression that is 5.

Then the compiler tries to convert value 5 to an object of type Point that to assign it to P0. As you have conversion constructor

```
Point (double xx=0, double yy=0): x(xx),y(yy){};
```

then the compiler calls it with arguments 5 and 0 that is as `Point( 5, 0 )`. This temporary object is assigned to P0.

You should use braced init list instead of the comma operator. For example

```
P0 = { 4, 5 };
```

provided that your compiler supports this feature of the C++ 11.
Otherwise you have to specify explicitly the constructor in the right side of the expression

```
P0 = Point( 4, 5 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use P0 = Point(4, 5) instead. Point(4, 5) call creates a temporary object which is then copied to P0 (in fact it is usually optimized so no actual copying is required).